# SSH tar and move to other server

Tags: ssh, terminal, command

I am using windows computer. I was trying to use SSH on my command prompt to tar (zip) a folder on my server and then transfer it to other server.

What I did is this:

```
ssh 188.166.177.20 username@hello1@3  tar latest - /var/www/foldertotar > 226.169.204.155 latest.tgz
```

But this one did not work. I basically set my password and username there including the server but it did not work.

Wondering what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `ssh` twice; once to run `tar` on one server, and again to connect to the other server. Connect the two with a pipe so that the output of `tar` goes to the other server.

```
ssh 188.166.177.20 'tar czf - latest' | ssh 226.169.204.155 'cat > latest.tgz'
```

`tar czf -` writes the compressed archive to standard output, which means it comes back to your local machine. Piping that to a remote `cat` process results in an archive on the other server.

Depending on your network setup, it may be more efficient to run `ssh` on the first remote machine to connect directly to the other server, rather than bringing the data back to your machine first.

```
ssh 188.166.177.20 'tar czf - latest | ssh 226.169.204.155 "cat > latest.tgz"'
```

(Reinsert usernames as needed.)

You can also invert the order of the `ssh` commands to avoid the need to run `cat`, redirection the output of `tar` directly to the destination file on the remote machine.

```
ssh 226.169.204.155 'ssh 188.166.177.20 "tar czf - latest" > latest.tgz'
```